# How to solve failed to resolve com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.library.2.1.4

Tags: android

How can i solve failed to resolve **com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.library.2.1.4** in android studio 3.0.1

Comment: Please show your build.gradle file.

Comment: com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.library:2.1.4

Answer (score 0):

The file name in the app library should have rather be 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4' instead of 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.library.2.1.4'

Note.
it is a seicolon (:) before and after the library instead of a dot(.)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this **implementation 'com.github.rengwuxian:MaterialEditText:2.1.4'**